# basic python while loop with break

Tags: python, while-loop

I have a basic python question.

I am querying an API that is sometimes time sensitive. I want to write a loop in python that allows for this. The functionality I want is as follows:

Query (return r), if the query is returned successfully then continue and return r.

If not, I want to add some time to the to the parameters of the query incrementally (so probably a for loop, for i in range(24 (hours)): then add one hour at a time until the query works.

If the query does not work after the for loop above then have some log error message.

I am struggling to get the ordering correct for the while/for loops. I could put a few of my attempts but I think it is more useful if I put it in pseudo code:

```
While True:
  if (r is not successful):
    i = 0:
    while i <= 24:
    add time and query again
    r <-- return query with new time
    i += 1
.......
return r
```

Something like this, how do I exit the loop when the query is returned correctly?

I also am not convinced my pseudo code is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Could this work?

```
def run_api():
    if success:
        return results
    else:
        return False

While True:
    results = run_api()
    if results:
        break
    else:
        sleep (however you have it coded)
return results
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .time() function.

```
import time

while True:
    results = query()

    if results:
        print(results) #or return to any datatype as required.

        time.sleep(wait_period_to_next_query)   #to be given in seconds

        break #if you want to exit the loop after 1 successful query
    else:
        print('Query unsuccessful, retrying after wait period.')
        time.sleep(wait_period)    #wait_period to be given in seconds
```

You can omit the break line if you want to continuously query the API.